# outputFileNameMapping and exclude problem with maven-assembly-plugin (3.1.0)

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project with two separate "main" projects (projectA and projectB) from which I would like to build a zip file (incl. all dependencies).
One of the dependencies "subProjectC" I would like to exclude. This is the relevant portion of assembly.xml:

```
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <!-- Enable access to all projects in the current multimodule build! -->
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

        <includes>
            <include>${project.groupId}:projectA</include>
            <include>${project.groupId}:projectB</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>${project.groupId}:subProjectC</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <binaries>
            <outputFileNameMapping>${module.artifactId}.${module.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
            <outputDirectory>project-root/lib</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

subProjectC turns up in the zip file nevertheless.

Also, all dependencies show up with their full version, e.g. projectA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, although the outputFileNameMapping should have prevented this...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems "outputFileNameMapping" only affects those artifacts that are specified in the "includes" list...